# Как объединить два массива и сделать отображения по порядку

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь объединить два массива первый массив

```
 $begin = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date("Y"));
    $end = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date("t"), date("Y"));

    $day = array();

    for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i += 86400)
    {
        if(date("w", $i) != 0 && date("w", $i) != 6)
            $day[] = array(
            'label' =>   date("Y-m-d", $i)
            );
    }
```

получаю  массив такого вида

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2017-03-01
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-02
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-03
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-04
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-05
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-06
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-07
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-08
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-09
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-10
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-11
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-12
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-13
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-14
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-15
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-16
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-17
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-18
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-19
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-20
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-21
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-22
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-23
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-24
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-25
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-26
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-27
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-28
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-29
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-30
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-31
    )
```

)

второй массив из базы

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
        [order_status_id] => 1
        [date_added] => 2017-03-18
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => 1
        [order_status_id] => 1
        [date_added] => 2017-03-21
    )
```

)

Как сделать что бы даты выводились по порядку ,

пример

```
 Array
    (
        [18] => Array
        (
            [label] => 2017-03-18
            [value] => 1
        )


        [20] => Array
    (
        [label] => 2017-03-21
        [value] => 1
    )............
```

Так весь массив а value было только там где даты совпадают

Comment: воспользуйтесь `group by`

Comment: Вы указали тег MySQL какое отношение вопрос имеет к данной СУБД ?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решения может кому то пригодиться

```
      $begin = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date("Y"));
    $end = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date("t"), date("Y"));

    $day = array();
    $format_day = array();
    for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i += 86400)
    {
        $day[] = array(
            'label' =>   date("Y-m-d", $i),
        );
        $format_day[] = array(
            'label' => date("d/m", $i)
        );
    }


    // new
    $array_date = $day;


    // второй массив из базы
    $orders_status_new = $this->model_account_order->getOrdersCountStatusNew();

    $array_new = array();
    foreach ($orders_status_new as $status_order){
        $array_new[] = array(
            'value' => $status_order['order_status_id'],
            'label' =>$status_order['date_added']
        );
    }

    foreach($array_date as $index => $value){
        $array_date[$index]['value'] = null;
    }

    $searchArray = array_column($array_date,'label');

    foreach($array_new as $value){

        $key = array_search($value['label'],$searchArray);
        if(!$key){
            echo sprintf("value %s not found<br/>",$value['label']);
            continue;
        }

        $array_date[$key]['value']=$value['value'];
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array_date);
```